# adding multiple products at once along with assigning attributes to all of them

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I swear this probably might the most complicated magento cart ever. But this is what the client request.

We are creating a web application that allows the customer to type in some letters. These letters appear on in a picture as if it was a sign.

Each word represents a products. The size of the word changes pricing. Also the custom can add a logo to the picture as well which are also prices

After its all said and done the product is sent to the shopping cart.

My problem is that the letters are products with attributes (small, medium, large trim color) and the logo's have attributes (small medium large, trim color). If each letter can have its own size , color and trim as well as the logo's. How am I suppose to send all that to the cart at once.

I think what will help me is if I can figure how to send multiple products and their attributes all in a single call.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds confusing to use :/

Depending on how many different base products there are, you might be able to do this mostly with product options, which would reduce some of the complexity. Otherwise, perhaps split each of the options into a simple product and send them as a bundle? Both of those solutions will display the "selection" as a single line but with all the options enumerated, and should be possible in code.